# What could cause this API Get request to not work?

Tags: api, parameters, get

I am making a GET request to the following url:

`http://testsurveys.com/surveys/demo-survey/?collector=10720`

and the request works fine. The point is to assign collector ID `10720` to the survey. There is absolutely no issue with this request. However, when I add another parameter the collector ID is passed through as a get parameter but it does nothing. For example:

`http://testsurveys.com/surveys/demo-survey/?code=123456&collector=10720`

Why does the collector parameter work in the first scenario but not in the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the code in your backend. There's nothing wrong with the second request. The fact that the parameters do get through to the other end is evidence of this. Try looking at your backend code and see why it isn't being processed properly. Were you coding it with any assumptions in mind that you ended up changing later? If you don't find anything, include the code in your question.

Comment: I have the GET parameters in a report. The first one says 'collector=10720' in the GET parameters field. The other says 'code=123456&collector=10720'. The code on my backend seems irrelative, I was just questioning if I'm adding multiple parameters correctly. I can't find out why the first assigns the survey to a collector and the second doesn't.

Comment: I should've been more clear. Yes, that's the correct way to pass multiple parameters. The format for HTTP query parameters is: ?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3... However, it's impossible to figure out why the second query doesn't assign the survey to a collector without looking at the code that processes this request.

Comment: So, in the case that I am doing things correctly, why would the parameter work in the first scenario but not in the second? It doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: All the GET request does is make the request to the server and give it the parameters you specified. What the server does with those parameters is up to the server itself. For example, maybe it only looks at one parameter and ignores all others. The server can do whatever it wants with the parameters, so without access to the server's code, it's hard to determine why it's not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help.